# Dynamically display sum without submitting form in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, form-submit

I have a form that has its rows:

```
<label for="super3">Extra Hours</label>
        <input type="number" name="super3" value="0">
 <label for="supert">Total Sum</label>
        <input type="number" name="supert" value="<?php echo $load->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D1')->getFormattedValue() ?>">
```

In my excel file, I have a formula that sums the extra hours and displays the total. How can I display the sum dynamically when I change the extra hour value without submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create some endpoint which accepts extra hours value as POST parameter and returns the sum. You have to use JavaScript AJAX request to make request to it.